# Inheritance Copying Base class Constructor to Derived class Object

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

First of all I don't know what question could be best to explore it. You can change question if it is not good or related. But please try to understand my question.

This was our quiz.

**Quiz Question:** What need to Modify in class B to generate.

```
num=5
gum=10
```

**Original Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
class A{
    private:
        int num;
    public:
        A(int x=0):num(x){
        }
        A(const A& a):num(a.num){
        }
        void Display(){
            std::cout << "num=" << num << std::endl;
        }
        void SetNum(int x){
            num=x;
        }
};
class B: public A{
    private:
        int gum;
    public:
        B(int x=0, int y=0):A(x), gum(y){
        }
        B(const B& b){
            gum=b.gum;
        }
        void Display(){
            A::Display();
            std::cout << "gum=" << gum;
        }
};
int main(){
    B b1(5,10);
    B b2(b1);
    b2.Display();
    return 0;
}
```

I just placed `A::SetNum(5);` this code in B's class copy constructor.
and result is

```
num=5
gum=10
```

But when I remove `A::SetNum(5);` and run original code then it generate.

```
num=0
gum=10
```

Now I want to ask Why B's copy constructor didn't copy automatically A(x) field to b2 object in original code?

A's constructor `A(x);` is not field of Derived class? If yes It should copy to b2 object.

Comment: OMG. -_- understood. this code doing explicitly copy constructor so we need to copy all fields.. -_- STUPID MIND.. Thanks man..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I want to ask Why B's copy constructor didn't copy automatically A(x) field to b2 object in original code?

Because you explicitly write a copy constructor that doesn't do any copying in the base class:

```
B(const B& b){
    gum=b.gum;
}
```

Here, the base class sub-object gets default constructed.

The simplest solution is to remove your copy constructors. The compiler synthesized ones will do the right thing. Otherwise, fix your copy constructor:

```
B(const B& b): A(b), gum(b.gum) {}
```

Comment: thanks Already understood by above comment. Was forget for a while..!